# Get string from other string with match()

Tags: javascript, match

I try to get the `00-8`.

Why this code do not returns me the 00-8 ?

```
<script>

  var pageDetailsSecond = "a='00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4'";

  var phone1 = pageDetailsSecond.match("a='(.*)'");
  var phone1 = phone1[0];

  var card_Phone = phone1;

  alert(card_Phone);

</script>
```

Actually I get `a='00-8'`.

Comment: Because what you try to match includes a=...

Comment: check my somewhat more complete answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what you try to match includes a=....

But when you find it, you can strip it from the match found.

Checked with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbo5x9dx/

```
var pageDetailsSecond = "a='00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4'";
alert(pageDetailsSecond)

var phones = pageDetailsSecond.match("a='(.*?)'");
var phone1 = phones[1];    
alert(phone1)
```

** edit: ** fix for non-greedy match, checked with http://jsfiddle.net/pbo5x9dx/1/

Comment: Good but if my string is the following it doesn't work : `a='00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4'`.

Comment: then you need a non-greedy match with *? iso *

Answer (score 0):

Because the array returned by `match()` will contain the entire match in the first array slot, and the capture groups in subsequent elements.

The array contents will be:

```
[
    [0] = "a='00-8'",
    [1] = '00-8'
]
```

What you want is `phone1[1]` instead of `phone1[0]`, which contains just the portion of the match specified by your capture group `(.*)`.

---

Based on the updated question, the regex pattern should be changed to:

```
"a='(.*?)'"
```

By default, regex patterns try to match as much as possible (known as "greedy"). The pattern is saying "match *any* number of *any* characters between `'` characters. This now includes `00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4`. By adding the `?`, this changes the behaviour to "lazy". In other words, match as *little* as possible, and your regex is back to matching only `00-8` as before.

Comment: Good but if my string is the following it doesn't work : `a='00-8'b='13-'a+='00-2'b+='3333'c='4'`. Or if their are another thing after...

Comment: Assuming you still want to match the quoted contents after `a=`, then you should modify your regex. See my updated answer.